# Curl - getting JSESSIONID

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I am trying to get Session Value and store in the variable.. how can that be done?

**Example:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

**Output:**

```
[request_header] => POST /customer.jsp?c=4 HTTP/1.1 
 Host: webdadasasd.co.uk 
 Accept: */* 
 Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000-dsfsdfsdf-sdfsdfsd_:fsdfsdfds 
 Content-Length: 54 
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded )
```

I want to get the Cookie value only like this: JSESSIONID=0000-dsfsdfsdf-sdfsdfsd_:fsdfsdfds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use php's [http_parse_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php). (requires pecl_http)
If you don't have/want pecl_http, you can find alternatives in discussion on that php manual page.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do something like the following?

```
preg_match('/^Cookie: (\w\d)+/m', curl-getinfo($ch), $matches);
```

The regex isn't that good - it would likely need tightening up with regards to the subpattern I have there used.  However, I have just tested the regex and it works as intended.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [request_header] is a single value, so I would use the following regex:

```
preg_match('/Cookie: ([[:graph:]]+)/', curl-getinfo($ch)['request_header'], $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Tested with http://www.quanetic.com/Regex

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php